# Check any new Latitude and Longitude is within 100 meter range or not? from my current location

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have data set with shops Latitude and Longitude, how do i find shops in 100 meter range from my current location(latitude,longitude)?

Comment: your question is incomplete. do you want to calculate the distance between 2 points and as answered by jo_va or it is something like google map distance(road distance from one shop too another)? are you fetching latitude and longitude from database?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate distance between two latitude-longitude points? (Haversine formula)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points-haversine-formula)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) for that.

```js
function distance(coords1, coords2) {
  const { lat: lat1, lon: lon1 } = coords1;
  const { lat: lat2, lon: lon2 } = coords2;
  const degToRad = x => x * Math.PI / 180;
  const R = 6371;
  const halfDLat = degToRad(lat2 - lat1) / 2;  
  const halfDLon = degToRad(lon2 - lon1) / 2;  
  const a = Math.sin(halfDLat) * Math.sin(halfDLat) + 
            Math.cos(degToRad(lat1)) * Math.cos(degToRad(lat2)) * 
            Math.sin(halfDLon) * Math.sin(halfDLon);  
  const c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a)); 
  return R * c; 
}

const paris = { lat: 48.864716, lon: 2.349014 };
const newYork = { lat: 40.730610, lon: -73.935242 };

console.log(distance(paris, newYork), 'km');
```

Then you simply need to iterate over your shops, calculate their distance to your location with the above function and only keep those whose distance is less than 100 meters.

I don't know how your data is structured, but if your shops are in an array, you could use `filter`:

```
const shopsNearMe =
    shopLocations.filter(shop => distance(shop.coords, myLocation) <= 0.1);
```